# Receive more than 1000 commits

Tags: github-api

Using a keyword ("data analysis") how is it possible to retrieve using github api all commits for this keyword?

Currently the general search provides only the first 1000 commits. Example link `https://github.com/search?q=%22data+analysis%22&type=commits`

Comment: The API uses [pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#pagination) for queries with many results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gh api paginate`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) to manage getting *all* results

```
gh api search/repositories --method=GET -F q="data analysis" --jq ".items[].html_url"  \
   -F per_page=100 --paginate --cache 1h
```

That won't be limited to the first 100.